# how do I get the 'which' command to resolve symlinks?

Tags: which

I've symlinked a script file into my ~/bin, and when I do `which foo` the output is:

`/Users/me/bin/foo`

Is there a way to have this resolve the symlink and show me the real file?

Answer (score 4):

use `readlink`

```
readlink -f "$(which command)"
```

Comment: Except the OP's `/Users` suggests he's on macOS and macOS' `readlink` doesn't support the `-f` option.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -r =foo(:A)
```

Or if `foo` is in the `$cmd` variable:

```
print -r $cmd:c:A
```